# Use a class as a selector for particles.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, particles.js

I have the following code which adds particles.js to a element by its id (fixed-back-canvas) but I can't seem to set it to select a class rather than id. Adding `.somediv #fixed-back-canvas` instead of `fixed-back-canvas` doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
particlesJS("fixed-back-canvas", {
    "particles": {
      "number": {
        "value": 60,
        "density": {
          "enable": true,
          "value_area": 800
        }
      },
      "color": {
        "value": "#ffffff"
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": "circle",
        "stroke": {
          "width": 0,
          "color": "#000000"
        },
        "polygon": {
          "nb_sides": 5
        },
        "image": {
          "src": "img/github.svg",
          "width": 100,
          "height": 100
        }
      },
      "opacity": {
        "value": 0.3,
        "random": true,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 1,
          "opacity_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "size": {
        "value": 3,
        "random": true,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 10,
          "size_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "line_linked": {
        "enable": false,
        "distance": 150,
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "opacity": 0.4,
        "width": 1
      },
      "move": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 2,
        "direction": "none",
        "random": true,
        "straight": false,
        "out_mode": "out",
        "bounce": false,
        "attract": {
          "enable": false,
          "rotateX": 600,
          "rotateY": 1200
        }
      }
    },
    "interactivity": {
      "detect_on": "canvas",
      "events": {
        "onhover": {
          "enable": true,
          "mode": "grab"
        },
        "onclick": {
          "enable": true,
          "mode": "push"
        },
        "resize": true
      },
      "modes": {
        "grab": {
          "distance": 140,
          "line_linked": {
            "opacity": 1
          }
        },
        "bubble": {
          "distance": 400,
          "size": 40,
          "duration": 2,
          "opacity": 8,
          "speed": 3
        },
        "repulse": {
          "distance": 200,
          "duration": 0.4
        },
        "push": {
          "particles_nb": 4
        },
        "remove": {
          "particles_nb": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
  });
```

Comment: is `fixed-back-canvas` the class name? if so you need to put a `.` infront of it like so `.fixed-back-canvas`

Comment: no that is the id

Comment: please show your code. this way it's not possible to resolve your issue

Comment: The js code is in my post, the top line selects fixed-back-canvas but i dont want to select that id, it needs to be that id but inside a class.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm afraid this library doesn't support that.

Comment: You can have _one_ id of that value anyway, so _" that id but inside a class"_ doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes but i only want it to load the particles if the body has a certain class set, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: you'll have to find another way to do that. That library doesn't support that on it's own.

Comment: ok thank you il try something else.